# Tentando exibir rand() apos inserir no db

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá,

Estou tentando exibir um numero aleatório com rand() depois de inseri-lo no banco de dados.
a inserção no mysql funciona normalmente, porem quando tento exibir uma mensagem com a variável $pedido não é mostrado nada.

Se eu inserir algo no banco usando uma variável essa variável passa a ser vazia depois da inserção?

Aqui está o código.

```html
<?php 
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$produto = $_POST['produto'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$pedido = rand(1,400);

if (insereProduto($conexao, $codigo, $produto, $valor, $pedido)) { ?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Pedido salvo com sucesso!
 </div>
 <?php
} else { ?>
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Pedido salvo com sucesso!,  O numero do pedido é <?php= $pedido; ?>
 </div>
<?php
}
 ?>
 <br />
<button class="btn btn-warning" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='novo-pedido.php'">Fazer novo pedido</button>
```

Comment: Ou você usa `<?php echo $pedido? >` ou você usa `<?= ?>` as duas formas são corretas. Acredito que seja esse o problema ali. Você está usando `<?php= $pedido ?>`.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo!

Comment: "Rafaéis" postem a resposta e aceitem para que se alguém tiver a mesma dúvida achar mais rápido.